# java : multiplying 2 doubles

Tags: java, math, numbers

```
double multiply() 
{
 double x=(2/3)*3.14*1.02;
 System.out.print(x);

 double y=0.666*3.14*1.02; /*(2/3)=0.666...*/
 System.out.print(y);
}
```

Output:
x=0.0
y=SomeNumber

please explain this?

Comment: Aren't you familiar with the joke?  You have 6 programmers and 5 slices of cake.  How much cake does each programmer get?  0, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(2/3) is 0.
```

because both are integers. To solve this, use a cast or make it clear that your number is not an integer:

```
double x=(2/3d)*3.14*1.02;
```

Now you have an integer divided by a double, which results in a double.

Some more to read about this:
http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/04/mixed.html

Comment: Not a good idea to write 3f in this case since 2/3f will be evaluated as a `float` which will cost you precision as the promotion to `double` happens subsequently.

Comment: *Much* nicer. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

`(2/3)` is computed first (because of the parentheses), **and** in integer arithmetic (since the number literals are of type `int`). The fractional part is discarded.

It is therefore an `int` type with a value of 0. The entire expression is therefore zero.

The obvious remedy is to remove the parentheses and write 2.0 / 3.0 instead. Some folk prefer an explicit cast, but I find that ugly.

Answer (score 0):

`2/3 = 0` because they don't have explicit cast to double they are integers. The whole expression becomes: `double x=0*3.14*1.02;`
which is 0.

Answer (score 0):

because data type of both 2 and 3 is int and int/int gives you int which in your case 2/3 is 0.
Try using 2.0/3 or 2/3.0 you will get the required answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suffix every number with a 'd' to be sure you are dealing with doubles